# Obtaining visa for Germany language course

Tags: visas, schengen, german-language

I am Brazilian and currently traveling in Europe. I am allowed to stay in the Schengen area for 90 days within 180 days. Im approaching the 90 days (80) but since I like it here so much and I might see a future here, I would like to do a German language course for half a year. The requirements sounds ok (course, financials, health insurance) but my main question is: can I get the visa while I am in Germany or do I have to go back to Brazil and how long does it take?